# docker-compose, depends_onで/etc/hostsにホスト名が追記されない。

Tags: docker, docker-compose

`depends_on`を使ってアプリケーションコンテナからDBコンテナに接続したいのですが、以下のようにdocker-compose.ymlを定義しましたが、接続できません。アプリケーションコンテナに入り、`/etc/hosts`を確認しましたが、dbコンテナのアドレスがありませんでした。`depends_on`にコンテナを登録すると自動的にそのコンテナのリンクが`/etc/hosts`に追記されるのではないのでしょうか。
参照: https://qiita.com/sivertigo/items/9baa73d922a68788402b

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: ./../../
    working_dir: /go/src/github.com/username/appname
    #restart: always
    env_file:
      - env
    depends_on: 
      - db
    command: sh /go/src/github.com/username/appname/wait.sh db /go/bin/appname
    logging:
      driver: syslog

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
      #MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
      MYSQL_USER: username
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    logging:
      driver: syslog

volumes:
  db_data:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM golang:alpine

ADD . /go/src/github.com/username/appname
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/username/appname
RUN apk add --update git
RUN apk add --update mysql-client

RUN go get -u github.com/Masterminds/glide
RUN glide install
RUN go install

EXPOSE 80
```

**wait.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"

until mysqladmin ping -h host --silent; do
  echo 'waiting for mysql'
  sleep 1
done

echo "MySQL is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.2  fadc826189c0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## dockerについて

`depends_on`は起動順序を制御するためのオプションであり
`depends_on`を指定したから名前解決できるようになる，というものではありません．

また，docker-composeを利用する場合，コンテナ間の名前解決には組込みDNSが利用されます．
同一のネットワークに配置されたコンテナは組込みDNSを用いて名前解決されるため
`/etc/hosts`にアドレスが記載されることはありません．
組込みDNSについては`/etc/resolv.conf`に`127.0.0.11`が指定されています．

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/

## appからdbへの接続について

スクリプトを見るとタイポのようです．
`wait.sh`において

> until mysqladmin ping -h host --silent; do

これは以下の間違いではないでしょうか．

> until mysqladmin ping -h $host --silent; do

おそらく名前解決自体はdockerではできているので
appコンテナ上から`ping db`など実行すれば
到達確認はできると思います．

Comment: ありがとうございます、無事接続できました。原因を調べているときに別のサイトで`/etc/hosts`に追記されると書かれているのを見たので、てっきりそうだと勘違いしてしまいました。